# Understanding SQL notification with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say we have a SQL Server database and a table `Orders` with columns `id, date, total, type_id`. This table is being updated very frequently (about every 5 seconds) and I would like to use an event listener, which is triggered on every `INSERT`.

Even more - I would like the event listener to send the newly inserted data to the listening function. Further more, I would like the trigger to work on a SQL `WHERE` condition (where as the last part with the `WHERE` cause is not mandatory for me) - so for example only trigger for specific data type: `WHERE Orders.type_id=2`.

Afaik one would use SQL Server notifications for this. If so, I would like to understand it more deeply. If it works, the way I understand it, the trigger would run every 5 sec - will the trigger wait for the script to end its work?

What does this mean for the performance - will my database be **much slower**? How can this be measured?

And what is the best way to implement this? I've read that there are different approaches - using C# or VB.

Comment: I would look at doing this via service broker.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166495(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you, I've read threw these articles - the service broker seems to be the solution, but how about the questions regarding the performance?